# Excel Formula - Map Two Column values with Third Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have below data in excel spreadsheet

```
customer_id  old_customer_id    parent_id
ACF00408     ALL02364           1819
ADA00856     ALT00420           1824
ALT00420                        1829
ALL02364     ADA00856           1834
ALL00523                        1839
AME02272     ACF00408           28921
```

How do I map column customer_id and old_customer_id to get their relevant parent_id as shown below

For example if `ACF00408` is found in both `customer_id` and `old_customer_id`, its parent_id should be `28921` and not `1819`

```
customer_id  parent_id
ACF00408     28921
ADA00856     1834
ALT00420     1824
ALL02364     1819
ALL00523     
AME02272
```

Tried with =VLOOKUP($A2, $B$2:$C$whatever, 2, 0) but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF()` and `Index/Match`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,F2)+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,F2)=2,INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how do I apply this formula? I have three columns in my excel currently. Based on the data I have it will be `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3140,F1)+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4853,F1)=2,INDEX($C$2:$C$5039,MATCH(F1,$B$2:$B$4853,0)),"")`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy - The ranges should all be equal sizes.  So, use the "biggest" row number to set everything.  So replace the last row number in each range with `5039` and that should work...assuming the data is indeed there.